# Show that $(I([0,1]), d_H)$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I want to show that the metric space $(I([0,1]), d_H)$ is complete, where $I([0,1])$ is the set of closed intervals $[a,b]$, $0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$, and $d_H$ is the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

I've tried to prove that the limit of every Cauchy sequence is in $I([0,1])$. Suppose we have a Cauchy sequence {$[a_k, b_k]$}, which induces the bounded sequences {$a_k$}, {$b_k$}. By Bolzano-Weierstrass, these two have convergent subsequences {$a_{n_k}$}, {$b_{n_k}$}, with limits
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} = a,$$
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} b_{n_k} = b.$$

And I guess I want to show that that $\lim_{k \to \infty} [a_k, b_k] = [a,b]$, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your question a while ago, but I didn't know how to answer it. As time have passed and nobody answered you, I'll write my approach, which I don't know if it's correct.

Let $\{[a_n,b_n]\}_{n\geq 1}\subset I([0,1])$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then, for every $\varepsilon>0$ exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d_H([a_n,b_n],[a_m,b_m])<\varepsilon$, for every $n,m>n_0$. Now, for intervals, the following relation is verified:
\begin{equation*}
d_H([a,b],[c,d])=\max\{|a-c|,|b-d|\}.
\end{equation*}

Then, in our case, for every $\varepsilon>0$ exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\max\{|a_n-a_m|,|b_n-b_m|\}<\varepsilon$, for every $n,m>n_0$. In other words, $|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon$ and $|b_n-b_m|<\varepsilon$, for every $n,m>n_0$. With this, we observe that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ are both Cauchy sequences of real numbers. Since $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is a complete space, there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n\rightarrow a$ and $b_n\rightarrow b$.

To end, let's see that $[a_n,b_n]\rightarrow [a,b]$, in the sense of the Hausdorff distance. Using the same property as before we have that
\begin{equation*}
d_H([a_n,b_n],[a,b])=\max\{|a_n-a|,|b_n-b|\}\rightarrow 0,
\end{equation*}
since $a_n\rightarrow a$ and $b_n\rightarrow b$. So, the Cauchy sequence $\{[a_n,b_n]\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a convergent sequence, which finish the proof.

I hope you find this useful and, if you spot any mistake in the reasoning, please comment it.

Comment: Your proof is totally correct. Only thing someone might worry about is $d_H([a, b], [c, d]) = \max\{|a-c|, |b-d|\}$. This can be checked by cases

Comment: Maybe it's also important to remark that since $a_n\geq 0$, $b_n\leq 1$ and $a_n\leq b_n, \forall n\geq 1$ (because $[a_n,b_n]\in I([0,1]), \forall n\geq 1$) then $a\geq 0$, $b\leq 1$ and $a\leq b$, so the limit verifies $[a,b]\in I([0,1])$.